# How can I send a Winsock response in hex format?

Tags: c++, request, winsock

I'm trying to send response with this code:

```
//s is  Accepted Client 

char* buf = "0x11";      
send(s, buf, 8, 0);
```

I have some documentation that states:

> For each incoming packet server must receive acknowledgment byte (indicates, that packet was received successfully): `0x11`

I'm new in System programming (I'm a web developer); Can you help me to understand how to send a byte packet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For each incoming packet server must receive acknowledgment byte (indicates, that packet was received successfully): 0x11

You probably need to send just one byte then:

```
char byte = 0x11;
send(s, &byte, 1, 0);
```

Or as a one liner:

```
send(s, "\x11", 1, 0);
```